# Remove [EXTERNAL] from subject line and caution box from e-mail body when e-mail arrives

Tags: vba, outlook

Our organization added `[EXTERNAL]` to the subject line of external e-mails, and also added a "Caution:" verbiage in the body of the e-mail. They also did not fix iterations, so every time it is replied to it adds another `[EXTERNAL]` and "Caution:" verbiage.

I have cobbled together two different scripts from the internet to remove this verbiage when I send an e-mail, but would like it to run when an e-mail arrives. The current script prompts for `MsgBox`, basically because I don't know how to remove them.

```
Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Item.HTMLBody = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, "CAUTION: This email originated from outside of the organization. Do not reply, click links, or open attachments unless you recognize the sender and know the content is safe.", "")
    Dim strSubject As String

    If InStr(Item.Subject, "[EXTERNAL]") > 0 Then
       'If you don't want the prompt,
       'You can remove the MsgBox line and its correspoding "Else … End If" lines.
       If MsgBox("Do you want to remove the prefix '[EXTERNAL]'?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
          strSubject = Replace(Item.Subject, "[EXTERNAL]", "", vbTextCompare)
       Else
          strSubject = Item.Subject
       End If
    End If

    If InStr(Item.Subject, "[EXTERNAL]RE:") > 0 Then
       If MsgBox("Do you want to remove the prefix '[EXTERNAL]RE:'?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
          strSubject = Replace(Item.Subject, "[EXTERNAL]RE:", "", vbTextCompare)
       Else
          strSubject = Item.Subject
       End If
    End If

    Item.Subject = Trim(strSubject)
    Item.Save
End Sub
```

When a message arrives, the script will run removing all iterations of `[EXTERNAL]`, leave the remaining words in the subject line, and remove the caution verbiage

Comment: @0m3r Thank you for the suggested edits to the question. Hopefully that will make it easier for someone to assist with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer.  I need you to discover some information and this answer gets you to do the discover while I code the next bit of the answer.

**Some comments on your existing code**

*Issue 1*

You say you do not know how to remove the prompts.  The relevant code is;

```
'If you don't want the prompt,
'You can remove the MsgBox line and its correspoding "Else … End If" lines.
If MsgBox("Do you want to remove the prefix '[EXTERNAL]'?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
  strSubject = Replace(Item.Subject, "[EXTERNAL]", "", vbTextCompare)
Else
  strSubject = Item.Subject
End If
```

The comment is not very helpful.  If you have a moderate understanding of VBA (or of any language with an If...Then…Else…End If construct), you would know how to remove the prompt.  If you do not have a moderate understanding, the comment is unclear.  The author means, do this:

```
Remove If MsgBox("Do you want to remove the prefix '[EXTERNAL]'?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
Keep     strSubject = Replace(Item.Subject, "[EXTERNAL]", "", vbTextCompare)
Remove Else
Remove   strSubject = Item.Subject
Remove End If
```

That is, remove the `MsgBox` line, remove the `Else…End If` lines and keep all lines between `Then` and `Else`.

*Issue 2*

You have a second block that removes “[EXTERNAL]Re:”.  This will not work properly.

The first block has placed the edited or non-edited subject in variable `strSubject`.  The second block checks `Item.Subject` so anything the first block did will be lost.

If you amended the second block to check variable `strSubject`, it still would not work because you have removed all the “[EXTERNAL]”s so there will be no “[EXTERNAL]Re:”s to find.   If you want to remove all “Xxxx”s and all “XxxxYyyy”s from a string, you must remove the longer substring first.

*Issue 3*

I do not think the second block could have the effect you seek.  Most (All?) email packages add “Re: ” or “RE: ” something similar to the subject for a reply.  Why only remove “Re:” from external emails.  I would remove all or none.  I suspect you are trying to handle this situation:

- Outsider John sends you an email with subject “xxxxxxx”
- This subject is changed by your system to “[EXTERNAL]xxxxxxx”.
- You reply and Outlook adds “RE: ” to give “RE: [EXTERNAL]xxxxxxx”
- John replies and your system changes the subject to “[EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]xxxxxxx”.
- You reply and Outlook adds “RE: ” to give “RE: [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]xxxxxxx”.

If you add code to remove “[EXTERNAL]”, you will have subjects such as “Re: Re: xxxxxxx” and “Re: Re: Re: xxxxxxx” and “Re: Re: Re: Re: xxxxxxx” depending on how long the email rally has lasted before the “[EXTERNAL]”s were removed.  Perhaps removing all the “[EXTERNAL]Re: ”s before removing the “[EXTERNAL]”s would help.

*Issue 4*

Do not save an email unless you have changed it.  Your code saves the email even if it is unchanged.  I do not know everything that happens when you save an email but I do know Outlook saves the time the email was amended and clearly has to find space for the amended email and to discard the original version.

You need something like:

```
strSubject = Item.Subject

Code to perform Edit 1 if appropriate.
Code to perform Edit 2 if appropriate.
Code to perform Edit 3 if appropriate.
    :    :    :    :    :    :    :

If strSubject <> Item.Subject Then
  Item.Subject = strSubject
  Item.Save
End If
```

**Designing your new code**

To my mind you have three requirements:

1. Remove “[EXTERNAL]” from the subject and “Caution ...” from the body of new emails.
2. Tidy any existing emails in your Inbox, Sent Items or other folders.
3. Tidy any new replies from Outsiders to your replies.

I am hopeful that code for requirement 2 will also handles requirement 3 but this is not certain.  Requirement 1 is the urgent requirement since, once this requirement is met, the situation is not going to get worse.  Tidying emails to which you wish to reply will come next.  Tidying old conversations can be handled when you have a spare moment.

To be able to test the code I think will help, I needed some test emails.

Within a secondary account I created a simple email.  I then added “[EXTERNAL]” to the subject and “Caution email from external source” to the body in an attempt to match what your system does.  I sent that email to my main account where I replied to it.  Back at my secondary account I created a reply and again added “[EXTERNAL]” and “Caution email from external source”.  After a couple or repeats, I had this email:

```
Subject: [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]Test

Caution email from external source

Reply 4

From: Tony@AcmeProducts.com
Sent: 04 April 2019 13:33
To: John@SomeOtherCompany.com
Subject: RE: [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]Test

Reply 3

From: John@SomeOtherCompany.com
Sent: 04 April 2019 13:30
To: Tony@AcmeProducts.com
Subject: [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]Test

Caution email from external source

Reply 2

From: Tony@AcmeProducts.com
Sent: 04 April 2019 13:20
To: John@SomeOtherCompany.com
Subject: RE: [EXTERNAL]Test

Reply 1

From: John@SomeOtherCompany.com
Sent: 04 April 2019 12:04
To: Tony@AcmeProducts.com
Subject: [EXTERNAL]Test

Caution email from external source

Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.
```

The above is what I see when I open the email except that I have amended the “To” and “From” values to conceal my email addresses.

Your caution text will be different from mine.  You can probably just delete the string you see but it is possible you cannot so you must identify what exactly is within the Html body.

Copy the following to an Outlook module:

```
Public Sub CallSubForSelectedEmails()

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      If ItemCrnt.Class = olMail Then
        Call DsplCautionText(ItemCrnt)
      End If
    Next
  End If

End Sub
Sub DsplCautionText(ItemCrnt As Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim LcHtmlBody
  Dim PosCaution As Long
  Dim PosDsplStart As Long

  With ItemCrnt

    LcHtmlBody = LCase(.HtmlBody)
    PosCaution = 1

    Debug.Print "-----" & .ReceivedTime & " " & .Subject

    Do While True
      PosCaution = InStr(PosCaution, LcHtmlBody, "caution")
      If PosCaution = 0 Then
        ' No [more] cautions
        Exit Do
      End If
      If PosCaution <= 20 Then
        PosDsplStart = 1
      Else
        PosDsplStart = PosCaution - 20
      End If
      Debug.Print PadL(PosDsplStart, 5) & " " & TidyTextForDspl(Mid$(.HtmlBody, PosDsplStart, 200))
      PosCaution = PosCaution + 1
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
Public Function TidyTextForDspl(ByVal Text As String) As String

  ' Tidy Text for dsplay by replacing white space with visible strings:
  '   Leave single space unchanged
  '   Replace single LF by                  ‹lf›
  '   Replace single CR by                  ‹cr›
  '   Replace single TB by                  ‹tb›
  '   Replace single non-break space by     ‹nbs›
  '   Replace single CRLF by                ‹crlf›
  '   Replace multiple spaces by            ‹# s›       where # is number of repeats
  '   Replace multiple LFs by               ‹# lf›      of white space character
  '   Replace multiple CRs by               ‹# cr›
  '   Replace multiple TBs by               ‹# tb›
  '   Replace multiple non-break spaces by  ‹# nbs›
  '   Replace multiple CRLFs by             ‹# crlf›

  ' 15Mar16  Coded
  '  3Feb19  Replaced "{" (\x7B) and "}" (\x7D) by "‹" (\u2039) and "›" (\u203A)
  '          on the grounds that the angle quotation marks were not likely to
  '          appear in text to be displayed.
  '  5Feb19  Add code to treat CRLF as unit
  ' 28Mar19  Code to calculate PosWsChar after "<x>...<x>" converted to "<# x>"
  '          incorrect if "<x>...<x>" at the start of the string.  Unlikely it
  '          was correct in other situations but this did not matter since the
  '          calculated value would be before the next occurrence of "<x>...<x>".
  '          But, if the string was near the beginning of the string, the
  '          calculated value was negative and the code crashed.

  Dim InsStr As String
  Dim InxWsChar As Long
  Dim NumWsChar As Long
  Dim PosWsChar As Long
  Dim RetnVal As String
  Dim WsCharCrnt As Variant
  Dim WsCharValue As Variant
  Dim WsCharDspl As Variant

  WsCharValue = VBA.Array(" ", vbCr & vbLf, vbLf, vbCr, vbTab, Chr(160))
  WsCharDspl = VBA.Array("s", "crlf", "lf", "cr", "tb", "nbs")

  RetnVal = Text

  ' Replace each whitespace individually
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, WsCharValue(InxWsChar), "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›")
  Next

  ' Look for repeats. If found replace <x><x><x><x>... by <# x>
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    'Debug.Assert InxWsChar <> 1
    PosWsChar = 1
    Do While True
      InsStr = "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›"
      PosWsChar = InStr(PosWsChar, RetnVal, InsStr & InsStr)
      If PosWsChar = 0 Then
        ' No [more] repeats of this <x>
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' Have <x><x>.  Count number of extra <x>s
      NumWsChar = 2
      Do While Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr), Len(InsStr)) = InsStr
        NumWsChar = NumWsChar + 1
      Loop
      RetnVal = Mid(RetnVal, 1, PosWsChar - 1) & _
                "‹" & NumWsChar & " " & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›" & _
                Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr))
      PosWsChar = PosWsChar + Len(InsStr) + Len(NumWsChar)

    Loop
  Next

  ' Restore any single spaces
  RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, "‹" & WsCharDspl(0) & "›", " ")

  TidyTextForDspl = RetnVal

End Function
```

I will explain the above code later.  For the moment, I just want you to select a number of these external emails and run macro `CallSubForSelectedEmails()`.  With my emails, I get Immediate Window output of:

```
-----04/04/2019 13:34:24 [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]Test
 2161 ><p class=MsoNormal>Caution email from external source<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp; … 
 3551 ><p class=MsoNormal>Caution email from external source<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp; …
 4986 ><p class=MsoNormal>Caution email from external source<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp; …
-----04/04/2019 13:30:10 [EXTERNAL]RE: [EXTERNAL]Test
 1953 ><p class=MsoNormal>Caution email from external source<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp; …
 3290 ><p class=MsoNormal>Caution email from external source<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp; …
-----04/04/2019 12:04:09 [EXTERNAL]Test
 1563 ><p class=MsoNormal>Caution email from external source<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp; …
```

Note 1: the ... indicates I have truncated the lines.  Note 2: the first caution text is at character position 1953 within the Html body since there are a lot of characters in the header.  Note3: for each line I have searched for “Caution” and then displayed 200 characters starting 20 characters back.  I have truncated the lines because, in this case, I did not need all this information.  I am hoping you do not either.

Anything in angle brackets is an Html tag.  “<p class=MsoNormal>” is a start tag.  “</p>” is an end tag.  For my emails, the caution text does not contain any tags.  This means I can replace “Caution email from external source” by “” without interfering with the Html.  I expect your caution text is similar but it might not be.

Please run macro `CallSubForSelectedEmails()` as I asked.  Is your caution text simple?  Is every example the same?

Comment: Hi Tony, Thank you for your detailed response. I was able to find a code that is working after our IT dept updated the server prepend to remove iterations of [EXTERNAL].https://techniclee.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/stripping-re-fw-and-fwd-from-the-subject-line/      - I was able to find and replace FW: with [EXTERNAL] Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. - I hope you get the credit you earned with your thoughtful response! Cheers!

Comment: @MacrolessinMontana  I am pleased you found what you needed.  I said I would explain the code I posted.  Would it be helpful if I added that explanation?